# How do I change the format for my uptime command its currently hours I would like to change it to days

Tags: javascript, html, math

I need to change my return time settings from hours to days.
I've tried to expand the hours but I keep getting errors.

```
let totalSeconds = (client.uptime / 1000);
let hours = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600);
totalSeconds %= 3600;
let minutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60);
let seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
// Then you'll have hours, minutes and seconds ready to use.

let uptime = `${hours} hours, ${minutes} minutes and ${seconds} seconds`;
```

I just keep getting errors.

Comment: Can you please update the error log??

Answer (score 1):

Converting hours to days would be extremely simple - you just divide by 24 and floor it:

```
var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
```

Hopefully this helps!